# Dev Platform to talk to PMBus/SMBus/I²C Power Supplies

Tags: power-supply, i2c, smbus

I am looking for a simple way to talk to PMBus power supplies (ie. get current information, turn power supply on or off, etc). This is normally integrated on computer main boards or server main boards.

Would anybody know any way that allows me to communicate with PMBus/SMBus from a computer or serial device etc, apart from creating something completely from scratch?

Answer (score 2):

http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/Bus_Pirate

Not sure about SMBus support, but this platform is Open Source. You could add your own SMBus support.

Answer (score 0):

Do a web search for "I2C USB adapter". You'll find plenty of pre-made, under $50 devices available.